# Django Sum in Annotate

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Good afternoon,

I am really struggling with getting a sum using Annotate in DJango.

I am using User object and the following models:

```
class Depts(models.Model):
    dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    dept_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    isBranch = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.dept_name)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Depts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dept", null=True)

class ActivityLog(models.Model):
    activity_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='activity_user')
    activity_category = models.ForeignKey(ActivityCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='activity_cat')
    activity_description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Misc Activity")

class ActivityCategory(models.Model):
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    activity_description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    pts = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.activity_name)
```

What I need to do is get a group of departments with aggregating the sum of the pts earned by all the users activitylogs.

So a user is part of  department, they do activities, each activity is of a type activity_category and has associated points.  How can I query using the ORM to get a sum of points for everyone in each department?

Thank you, I cannot seem to wrap my mind around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You annotate the departments with the sum:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Depts.objects.annotate(
    total_pts=Sum('dept__user__activity_user__activity_category__pts')
)
```

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `Depts` model to the `UserProfile`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`dept`</s> relation to `userprofiles`.

After setting the `related_name='userprofiles'`, the query is:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Depts.objects.annotate(
    total_pts=Sum('userprofiles__user__activity_user__activity_category__pts')
)
```

Comment: You are awesome.  And tremendously helpful...  Thank you!  Just seeing it the right way helps it make sense.